# Opening and closing database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm working on an application that records do my MySql database on my server. Every time I want to use the database, get the existing connection, if not, I think for the first time. When I do an insert or select, works very well, but followed that consultation, when it ends, I can never regain the connection and do not return to consultations.

My class of Database

```
public class Database {
/**
 * Gets just one instance of the class
 * Connects on construct
 * @returns connection
 */
private Connection _conn = null;
private long timer;

//singleton code
private static Database DatabaseObject;
private Database() {}
public static Database connect() {
    if (DatabaseObject == null)
        DatabaseObject = new Database();
    return DatabaseObject._connect();
}
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
}
//end singleton code


/**
 * Connects with the defined parameters on Config
 * Prevents re-connection if object was already connected
 * @throws SQLException
 */
private Database _connect() {
    try {
    if (this._conn == null || !this._conn.isValid(0)) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Properties connProps = new Properties();
            connProps.put("user", Config.Config.DB_USER);
            connProps.put("password", Config.Config.DB_PASS);
            this._conn = DriverManager.
                        getConnection("jdbc:" + Config.Config.DB_DBMS + "://" + Config.Config.DB_HOST + ":"
                                + Config.Config.DB_PORT + "/" + Config.Config.DB_NAME, Config.Config.DB_USER, Config.Config.DB_PASS);
            timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to DB");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            long tmp = System.currentTimeMillis() - timer;
            if (tmp > 1200000) { //3600000 one hour ; 1200000 twenty minutes
                System.out.println("Forcing reconnection ("+tmp+" milliseconds passed since last connection)");
                this.close();
                this._connect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Forcing reconnection");
            this._conn = null;
            this._connect();
        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return this;
}

/**
 * Closes connections
 * This has to be invoked when database connection is no longer needed
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public void close() throws SQLException {
    if (this._conn != null) {
        this._conn.close();
        this._conn = null;
    }
}

   /**
    * Getter for connection
    * @return
    */
   public Connection get() {
      return this._conn;
   }
}
```

The following function I make a query:

```
private Statement sment = null;
private PreparedStatement psment = null;
private ResultSet rset = null;
public boolean existsByNameAndUserId(String md5, int userId, int eventId) {
    Connection conn = Database.connect().get();
    try {
        psment = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM files "
                                        + "WHERE user_id = ? AND md5 = ? AND evento_id = ?");
        psment.setInt(1, userId);
        psment.setString(2, md5);
        psment.setInt(3, eventId);
        rset = psment.executeQuery();

        if (rset.next()) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}

private void close() {
    try { if (rset != null) rset.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());};
    try { if (psment != null) psment.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());};
    try { if (sment != null) sment.close(); } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());};
}
```

And in the next, I call the above function to find out whether or not a record with these characteristics, if not, I do an insert.

```
String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO files (evento_id, user_id, path, thumb, preview, width, height, md5, numero_corredor, created, modified) "
        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),NOW())";
public void save(List<components.File.Schema> files) throws SQLException {
    try (
            Connection conn = Database.connect().get();
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
        ) {
            int i = 0;

            for (components.File.Schema file : files) {
                if(!existsByNameAndUserId(file.getMd5(), file.getUserId(), file.getEventId())){
                    statement.setInt(1, file.getEventId());
                    statement.setInt(2, file.getUserId());
                    statement.setString(3, file.getPath());
                    statement.setString(4, file.getPreview());
                    statement.setString(5, file.getThumb());

                    statement.setInt(6, file.getWidth());
                    statement.setInt(7, file.getHeight());
                    statement.setString(8, file.getMd5());
                    statement.setString(9, null);
                    statement.addBatch();
                    i++;
                    if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == files.size()) {
                        statement.executeBatch(); // Execute every 1000 items.
                    }
                }
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Please check - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Tries to provide the code and be as explanatory as possible, yet not understood? I will try to write and add more code. @Razib

Comment: No, In my opinion the best question is one which is concise and easily understood.

Comment: My problem is because when making a database query wing works well, the second failure. No returns values, does not fall into exceptions and not get errors. Simply the database as the connection is lost, I tried to figure out the problem but can not find the reason. Every time I use the database get existing connection, if established, I think a new but this does not work for me.

Comment: @Razib edit my post, hopefully understand it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to the fact that you put `Connection conn = Database.connect().get()` in a `try-with-resources` statement which is what you are supposed to do but it closes your connection and when you call it again as the method `_connect()` doesn't have a valid test, it doesn't create a new connection. The valid test is `this._conn == null || !this._conn.isValid(0)`, indeed in your original test you call `this._conn.isValid(0)` which will returns `false` in our context since the connection is closed so it won't create a new connection which is not what we want here.

**Response Update:** The second part of the problem is the fact that in the save `method` you call `existsByNameAndUserId` which closes the current connection, you should only close the statement and let the method save close the connection.

Comment: Nicolas, Hello, thanks for answering. I understand what you say, I think I miss me add a method code close (), since in this method I do not close the database, editare and fails in my post code

Comment: No need to add a close method as a Connection is AutoCloseable so it is called already within the context of the try-with-resources statement

Comment: I understand and modify my code to validate the connection as you said it but still works the same way. At the first consultation of the database, I can not access again,.

Comment: I tried but it's the same, edit my post so you see my code and see if anything I'm wrong for what you say is logical and should work,

Comment: If I were you I would use a Datasource instead but it is not the topic here, did you simply try to debug to see what happens?

Comment: It seems a little odd that does not receive any error. Try printing this._conn.isValid (0) but obviously receive the error that is null, it is the only error that I can get, but the code is still running queries to the database do not work. Chat I can give you more details of my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109455/discussion-between-hateful-and-nicolas-filotto).